# Formatting/fixing dimensions inside text input

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to push the input text slightly to the right so that it is not sitting right up against the edge?

[image: input]

So that 'searching' is 5px to the right?

Comment: Have you tried anything, oh say like padding?

Comment: @j08691 I feel like such an idiot now. Padding keeps slipping my mind. Thanks.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes:

```
padding-left: 5px;
```

Applied to the containing box/field.

Also: Use padding-right for the "search" on the left. 
Alternatively, you might consider

```
text-align: center;
```

Though, I wouldn't recommend it for the input field, but it would be fine for the "search" text.